# a relationship with the other

Tags: history-of-philosophy, aesthetics, sociology

Bourriaud somewhere says:

> “artistic practice is always a relationship with the other, at the
>   same time as it represents a relationship with the world”.

Does he by *"with the other"* mean *"with other artistic practices"* or *"with other things including people, places, things, ..."*?

Comment: Alterity is a very general concept: it definitely can mean the other person, but also just an "outside" of myself (the world, the universe)

Comment: But that reading just makes the statement, which appears to be trying to create a contrast, redundant, instead. So we can surmise that the other here is more personal than the world at large. Given that he is late in history and French, he is probably influenced by Critical Theory and may be adopting a psychoanalytic notion of 'other' as the 'other within': the Kleinian introjection of significant objects (e.g. family, community, religion...) which become parts of our self-image by contrast and adaptation.

Comment: Zizek mentions a big Other, and I guess there must be a little other...